# Can't empty array between submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'v been struggling with this problem for quite long now. I have an array where I'll be pushing numbers on button click to array like [2,6,8]. I tried emptying the array between submits with another button click but I'm unsuccessful. Can someone point out my mistake? The array keeps printing the first result even if I try to format and change it many times after that. The data-index also changed correctly in the DOM. I tried to empty the array also at the start of #accept click, but with no effect.

```
var mediaArray = [];

$( "#clearAll" ).click(function() {
        mediaArray = [];
        console.log("i can see this");
});

$( "#accept" ).click(function() {
        var firstRound = true;
        var mediaLength = 0;
        var eachData = 0;
        $( ".slots" ).each(function(index) {
            if (!firstRound) {
                mediaLength++;
                if ($(this).data('index') != eachData) {
                    mediaArray.push(mediaLength);
                    mediaLength = 0;
                }
            }
            eachData = $(this).data('index');
            firstRound = false;
            console.log($(this).data('index'));
        });
        mediaArray.push(mediaLength+1);

        console.log(mediaArray);
});
```

Comment: it's working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/n0cfdxup/59/)

Comment: It must work check here the simple example https://jsfiddle.net/9oapu6pa/

Comment: please post complete HTML too, otherwise it will be difficult to trace the issue.

Answer (score 3):

that's pretty simple. It is due to your `firstRound` being `true` every time the click handler is invoked.

To fix it, you might want to have `firstRound` as a global variable, but that usually is not desired, in which case you can use an IIFE to make it local:

```
(function() {

    var firstRound = true;

    $( "#accept" ).click(function() {
        // ...
    });

}());
```

Comment: Sorry but that is not working. Ofc you cant know the whole situation and I cant paste the whole html+js, but this was not it.

Comment: ok, since you have those processing with your `.slot` items, I advise you `console.log("at beginning of handler", mediaArray);` to see if it got emptied out.  If it did, then your issue is due to something else.  It could be due to the logic with `.each` and adding data after the loop

Comment: another way is to simplify.  Just use only `mediaArray.push(Math.random());` and see if the array got cleared out and each time the new array contains only 1 item

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `firstRound` to be global. This will ensure it is set to `true` only in the first round. Right now it is being `true` at every call to `onClick` handler at id `#accept`.